# How to replace `peer_id` with `alias` in c-lightning?

Tags: core-lightning

There are commands like `lightning-cli listpeers` and `lightning-cli listfunds`.

How do I replace the `peer_id` in the output of the commands with the `alias` of the peer?

I know about the `jq` command line tool to parse JSON and that i can get the alias with `lightning-cli listnodes $peer_id`. But I am having a hard time achieving the desired output. I think it should be doable with the use of `jq`. But maybe there is another way I am not thinking about. Maybe Python? But I would prefer just the standard unix tools if possible.

Comment: unfortunately no for the moment